# How can I sort ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#

I've tried:

```
Persons = from i in Persons orderby i.Age select i;
```

But I cant convert Linqs `System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable` to `ObservableCollection<Person>`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to create a new instance of it.

```
Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>(from i in Persons orderby i.Age select i);
```

Comment: This may break any binding that's using the `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: @DavidS if the class containing it implements `IPropertyNotifyChanged`  and the property for the collection is set up properly then it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: it doesn't break anything, you have only to use some class for notify the update of the data

Comment: There really isn't any point to using an `ObservableCollection` if you're going to replace the whole thing each time.

Answer (score 1):

An `ObservableCollection` can take in an `IEnumerable<T>` (i.e, in this instance, your `IOrderedEnumerable`) from it's constructor:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You might want to simply create a new `ObservableCollection` from the sorted enumerable.