# Why is the ComboBox losing its SelectedItem when sorting the ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, combobox, observablecollection

Consider this simple example:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        x:Name="ThisControl">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Collection, ElementName=ThisControl}" SelectedItem="a" />
        <Button x:Name="SortButton">Sort</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WPF_Sandbox
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public ObservableCollection<string> Collection { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>(new [] { "b", "a", "c" });

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SortButton.Click += (s, e) => Sort(Collection);
        }

        public static void Sort<T>(ObservableCollection<T> collection)
        {
            var sortableList = new List<T>(collection);
            sortableList.Sort();

            for (var i = 0; i < sortableList.Count; i++)
                collection.Move(collection.IndexOf(sortableList[i]), i);
        }
    }
}
```

When starting the program, `a` is selected. On pressing `Sort` the selection doesn't change but the list gets sorted (still as expected).
If you a) press `Sort` again or b) select `b` or `c` before sorting, the `ComboBox` loses its selection and `SelectedItem` becomes `null`.

I pinpointed the issue down to the [`ObservableCollection.Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654933(v=vs.110).aspx) method. It appears that whenever you call `Move(i, i)` (so you do not actually move anything) with `i` being the `SelectedItem`, the selection goes to hell.

I'm not looking for a solution. Obvious workaround would be to not sort the `ObservableCollection` at all and use a `CollectionViewSource` or adjusting the `Sort` method to only call `Move` when the two indices actually differ.

The question I have is, why is this happening in the first place? There is no indication in documentation for the [`Move`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms654933(v=vs.110).aspx) method that you must not pass the same parameter twice. Also there is no hint why this would not work in the documentation for the [`CollectionChanged` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653375(v=vs.110).aspx) or the [`CollectionChangedEventArgs` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx). Is this a bug in WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this to be a bug in the implementation of the `ItemControl's` event handling. Take a look here:

```
case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
    // items between New and Old have moved.  The direction and
    // exact endpoints depends on whether New comes before Old.
    int left, right, delta;
    if (e.OldStartingIndex < e.NewStartingIndex)
    {
        left = e.OldStartingIndex + 1;
        right = e.NewStartingIndex;
        delta = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        left = e.NewStartingIndex;
        right = e.OldStartingIndex - 1;
        delta = 1;
    }

    foreach (ItemInfo info in list)
    {
        int index = info.Index;
        if (index == e.OldStartingIndex)
        {
             info.Index = e.NewStartingIndex;
        }
        else if (left <= index && index <= right)
        {
             info.Index = index + delta;
        }
    }
break;
```

[Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ItemsControl.cs,c826c1af3071b729)

The `if` statement does not seem to expect `e.OldStartingIndex` and `e.NewStartingIndex` to be of the same value which results in `delta` being `1` which then causes some unintended index manipulation inside of the `foreach` loop. I'm surprised it "only" deselects the item and not completely ruins the whole collection.

Comment: I have encountered exactly the same issue and was able to solve it thanks to your answer. I have created an extension method which checks if the old and new index differ before calling the Move method.