# How to sort ObservableCollection to alphabet in Xamarin.Form

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have ObservableCollection list and i want to sort it to alphabet 
for ex : when i enter 3 names (basketball , arab , club)
the output : 
basketball,
arab,
club

and i want it like :
arab,
basketball,
club,

this code for ObservableCollection :

```
        public ObservableCollection<Contact> ContactList { get; set; }
```

and this code of Add and Delete items

```
 public ContactsListView()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            ContactList = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();

            BindingContext =  new Contact();
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Contact>(this, "addNew", (addItem) =>
            {
                ContactList.Add(new Contact { Name = addItem.Name, PhoneNo = addItem.PhoneNo, Address = addItem.Address, NickName = addItem.NickName });

            });

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Contact>(this, "deleteContact", (Account) =>
            {
                ContactList.Remove(Account);
            });

                        MyListView.ItemsSource = ContactList;
            AddNewContact.Clicked+= AddNewContact_Clicked;
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort ObservableCollection<string> through C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112922/sort-observablecollectionstring-through-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than recreating a *new sorted* `ObservableCollection` to the `ContactList`, you could use `Move` method to sort the current `ContactList`.

```
private void SortContacts()
{
    // order by name
    var sortedContact = ContactList.OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

    for (var i = 0; i < sortedContact.Count; i++)
        ContactList.Move(ContactList.IndexOf(sortedContact[i]), i);
}
```

Call above method after adding or deleting contact item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linq to sort like this:

```
var sortedContactList = ContactList.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

You will need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Comment: I am not super clear on this but I think I have seen it mentioned that using linq on an ObservableCollection will break bindings.

Comment: Well, yes, you can't sort unless you have the full collection.

Answer (score 0):

> The ObservableCollection class itself does not have a sort method.
>   but by using collection you can recreate it.

```
var ContactList = new ObservableCollection<string> { "club", "arab", "basketball", };
 ContactList = new ObservableCollection<string>(ContactList.OrderBy(i => i));
```